# Claw-like gloves to simulate pick when playing fingerstyle?

Tags: guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, picks

I am wondering if clawed gloves would be able to reproduce the sound of a pick when playing fingerstlye.

Comment: Just use Finger Picks (as John B.  mentions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory if you were to attach claw like tips made of a typical pick material to a glove it would give you the sound of a guitar played with a pick.

In practice it would probably be very problematic at best. First there is the issue of the gloves themselves. They would have to be extremely tight and form fitting in order for the fingertips to stay put when plucking. The other issue is how the claws are integrated into the gloves. If they are not very securely connected the claws and even the gloves themselves will be sliding out of position constantly while trying to play.

A better solution is to use finger picks and a thumb pick. These are available everywhere and come in either metal or different types of materials used for making regular picks.

I don’t know what your reason is for wanting to know this, is it perhaps something visual you are going for? Whatever the reason, whatever is used to pluck a string has to be firmly attached to the fingers or it will be sliding around all over the place while trying to play.

Comment: I'm just cracking up over here imagining Wolverine with a banjo.

Comment: @AndyBonner, ah, but there’s a difference, his are built in…

Answer (score 1):

Fingerstyle masters like Guido use them. The second video in this article shows how (https://www.guitarworld.com/features/up-and-down-fingerstyle-gio-guido). Useful especially if you want to use your fingers both upwards and downwards like a pick as this article shows.